# Unicode escape characters are not getting parsed in Spring application.yml properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

I am trying to add a property value in `application.yml` file in Spring Boot which contains a trailing space. I'm retrieving the value using the `@Value` annotation. Leaving the space unescaped simply trims it and adding a Unicode escape character results in the following String `Example\u0020` being parsed by the application.

Initialising a String variable with `\u0020` directly in the code results in an expected space character.

Comment: @JoachimSauer that worked perfectly. I feel silly for not trying that. If you could add this as an answer I could mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unicode escapes in strings are only accepted [in double-quoted strings in YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2787109), so `"Example\u0020"` should work.

But simply quoting the string should also be sufficient: `"Example "`.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Unicode escaped symbols - what worked for me is that you encode the entire string. Also, try to use '\u00a0' instead of '\u0020' that symbol is known as "Non-breakable white space" (in HTML - &nbsp;) this definitely will not be trimmed out 
Obviously, there are several sites on the internet that can do that for you, but I also wrote an Open-source library that has a util that can encode plain text strings into Unicode-escaped strings and vice-versa. I found it to be very useful also when debugging various encoding issues. In any case if you want to use it here how the code would look like:

```
result = "Example ";
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence(result);
System.out.println(result);
result = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.decodeUnicodeSequenceToString(result);
System.out.println(result);
```

The result would be:

```
\u0045\u0078\u0061\u006d\u0070\u006c\u0065\u0020
Example
```

The library can be found at [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils/1.5.0.2/jar) or at [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt) It comes as maven artifact and with sources and javadoc

Here is javadoc for the class [StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.html)